# Perform segue between two view controllers where the button is on an SCNView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, scenekit, hittest

I am currently working with Scene Kit. I have Two view controllers which both use Scene Kit. In one of the view controllers I have a main Scene view called scnView and also have another sceneview on top of that called titleView. scnView and titleView were added through the storyboard.   titleView has a node that when pressed is supposed to segue from one view controller to another. So I created a gesture recognizer and used hit test.

In viewDidLoad I created a gesture recognizer.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(boardTapped:)];
NSMutableArray *gestureRecognizers = [NSMutableArray array];
[gestureRecognizers addObject:tapGesture];
[gestureRecognizers addObjectsFromArray:scnView.gestureRecognizers];
scnView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers;
```

In the boardTapped method, I created two CGPoints. One that detects a click in scnView, and one that detects a click in titleView.

```
 CGPoint p = [gestureRecognize locationInView:scnView];
NSArray *hitResults = [scnView hitTest:p options:nil];

CGPoint q = [gestureRecognize locationInView:_titleView];
NSArray *hitResultsTwo = [_titleView hitTest:q options:nil];


if([hitResults count] > 0){
    SCNHitTestResult *result = [hitResults objectAtIndex:0];
    if (result.node == boxOne)
    {  
        //do something
    }

if([hitResultsTwo count] > 0)
{
    SCNHitTestResult *result = [hitResultsTwo objectAtIndex:0];

    if(result.node == _titleView.menuBoxNode)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMainMenu" sender:nil];
        NSLog(@"Went into show main menu");
    }
}
```

A tap on the scnView is recognized perfectly. But a tap on titleView is not recognized and the segue doesn't happen. It actually does not even go into the if condition. Also one more point. I have it set up in scnView view so that if a double click occurs the view changes back to its original position. So I have a board that rotates and if the user double taps the board moves back to its original position. When the board is rotating and a double click on titleView occurs the board rotates back to its position, even though the double click was not in scnView.

Comment: Can we see a screenshot? I don't understand what you mean by "on top of".

Comment: I got it done. The problem was that I could not have two uiTapGestureRecognizers so the application didn't recognize which recognizer to activate when the touch was made. Thank you for your time tho.